# 'Link Table Manager' functionality Programatically using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, dao

I want to write some custom code to perform the 'Link Table Manager' operation programatically. I have MS-Access database which is currently referencing external data from Excel,MS-Access and SQL server.

Before executing a Macro on my MS-Access database, I want to re-link the external data sources or provide new location of the data-source in case there is change in the location of the data source.

I have a table in MS-Access database which is Linked to an external SQL data source(Test database). Now I want it to be linked to Production Database. I have tried the following code but it is throwing a COM-Exception with error description as 'ODBC--connection to 'EmployeeConnectionForSQL' failed.'

```
public void performLinkTableMangerOperationForSQL()
        {  
            string CurrentDatabasePath = @"D:\UDTDatabase\InternalDatabase.accdb";          

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine DAO = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database db;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.TableDefs dt;
            db = DAO.OpenDatabase(CurrentDatabasePath);
            dt = db.TableDefs;

            // Refreshing link for Sql server external table with DSN.
            string sqlSource = @"DATABASE=Employee;";
            string DSNName = "EmployeeConnectionForSQL;";           
            string sqlNewConnectionString = @"ODBC;FileDSN=" + DSNName + sqlSource;

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.TableDef table in dt)
            {
                string name = table.Name;
                if (table.Name == "dbo_Employees")
                {
                    table.Connect = sqlNewConnectionString;
                    table.RefreshLink();
                }
            }
         db.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `FileDSN` is clearly invalid. A `FileDSN` should point to a .dsn file. If you want to use a normal DSN, use `DSN=`, not `FileDSN=`. Since there's an invalid DSN, you can't relink.

I highly recommend you go DSNless, and just use a connection string, but providing a valid FileDSN should work too.

Comment: Hi @Erik Can you provide me the format for SQL connection string and Excel Connection string. Would be a great help!

Comment: Just check https://www.connectionstrings.com/. Make sure to prefix them with `ODBC;` to make them work with DAO.

Comment: I tried using the link for ODBC Driver 13, but getting a popup asking credentials and server SPN. Here is the link

"ODBC;Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}; Server ="+ serverName + "; DATABASE="+sqlDatabase+" Trusted_Connection = Yes;";

Comment: Well, you need a `;` semicolon after specifying the database, that's why it's not processing what's coming after that and not using a trusted connection.

Comment: I was putting a semicolon in the sqlDatabase string parameter at the end. I have tried putting it the connection string as well but to no avai

Comment: Then share the new string. Also, scrap the spaces in `Trusted_Connection = Yes`, you pretty much want 0 spaces in ODBC connection strings, besides the driver name and database name.

Comment: "ODBC;DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=XYZ\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=ProdEmployees;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

Comment: it worked ....May be it was one semicolon and one space...Million thanx man....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219335/discussion-between-nikhil-and-erik-a).